# "This tool has no parameters" after opening agent analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, agent-analyst, agent-based-modeling

I installed the agent analyst based on the data and the book available on this link http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/agent-analyst/
But after installing, I encounter the following when opening it "this tool has no parameters"

No one knows about this?
I've tried this thread on ArcMap 10.3 and 10.4.
[image]

Comment: No parameters have been set for the tool, what is it supposed to do? Tools with no parameters require specific names/paths. What's the first 10 or so lines of code say?

Comment: I am very beginner in this job, maybe you can help me more? What part of my work is?

Comment: Have you gone through the exercises in that linked page? I've got no idea what *agent analyst* is supposed to do, it's considered 3rd party Esri software.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you go through the exercises in the book  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/agent-analyst/pdf/AgentAnalyst.pdf , you will have a better understanding of Agent Analyst. The very first step is to click right on the "Tool" and click on "Edit" instead of "open". Then you can define your parameters.